# eslint tells me there are warnings, but doesn't show them

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint, eslintrc

I am using vscode with eslint. It shows me this:

[image]

How do I actually see what those errors and warnings are, so I can fix them?

Clicking on that blue bar takes me to line 4292 in the code, but there's no indication of what's wrong...

Comment: The `26` is the column number of that error - maybe that would help.